# Create a Custom Tag in JSP to get objects

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I want to create a custom tag which can retrieve a collection of objects sent by its `SimpleTagSupport` class. For example

```
<myTag:collection var="o" id="xx" />
```

Here `var="o"` is to hold the retrieved object of the collection. I am supposed to iterate it and do some stuff. Then `EL` is to be used to get the values of objects. Let me know any Sample code that shows how to write `SimpleTagSupport` class - the `doTag()` method is enough or any link where I can find a solution.

**Edit**
I have to got an object from the `session` and pass it to a java class to get a `resultSet` which contains a collection.
It can be done using scripts(`<%  .. %>`). But I think it is not a good practice. That is why I m seeking a solution with `EL` and `Tags`.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following links to the tutorial with clear examples, it will take anywhere between 1 hr to 2 hrs to go through but you will understand EL's concept nicely, worth a read.

1. Expression Language ([PDF](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/csajsp2/15-Expression-Language.pdf)), you can directly go to the section "Accessing Collections"
2. JSP-EL ([book chapter](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/JSP-EL.pdf))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following code we use it for a very large project if this is what
you want i will prepare explanation for it along with extra code for the cycle

```
<td height="30" nowrap  class="label" id="lblHumanTypes" dir="${local["OP_DIRECTION"]}">${descriptionsTable["EditEmHumanCases"]["ddlHumanTypes"]}</td>
                                        <td width="1%">:</td>
                                        <td height="30" style="text-align:${local["ALIGN"]}" colspan="3">
                                            <select  id="ddlHumanTypes" name="ddlHumanTypes" style="width:160px">
                                                <option value="-1">${local["SELECT"]}</option>
                                                <c:forEach var="humanTypes" items="${LK_HUMAN_TYPES}">
                                                    <c:if test="${humanTypes.key ne '1' and humanTypes.key ne '2' and humanTypes.key ne '3' and humanTypes.key ne '4' and param.humanTp eq humanTypes.key}">
                                                        <c:if test="${emHumanCasesView.humanTp eq humanTypes.key}">
                                                            <option value="${humanTypes.key}" selected>${humanTypes.value.humanTpDesc}</option>
                                                        </c:if>
                                                    </c:if>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td  id="msgHumanTypes"></td>
```

here LK_HUMAN_TYPES is loaded on deploy once from table oracle
there is a java class with setter and getter methods 
and 
private members
to use in jsp

Comment: Thanks for your attention. You have used `EL`.. Your code sounds that it may help me. Would you explain it? ( data insertion at the `<select> and <options>.. is a good point to me`) I edited my question again and just a take look at it too. Then my problem d be more clear to you.

Comment: i will explain it as soon as i can appx(after 12 hours) but am at work now :)